# SQL Running Query Subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

PO Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PO]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PONO] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ItemName] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [POQty] [float] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestPO] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

PO Insert

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PO] ON 
    
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[PO] ([ID], [PONO], [ItemName], [Color], [POQty]) 
 VALUES (1, N'K1', N'A1', N'C1', 5240)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[PO] ([ID], [PONO], [ItemName], [Color], [POQty]) 
 VALUES (2, N'K2', N'A1', N'C1', 393)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[PO] ([ID], [PONO], [ItemName], [Color], [POQty]) 
 VALUES (3, N'K3', N'A1', N'C1', 4847)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[PO] ([ID], [PONO], [ItemName], [Color], [POQty]) 
 VALUES (4, N'K4', N'A3', N'C3', 2968)
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[PO] ([ID], [PONO], [ItemName], [Color], [POQty]) 
 VALUES (5, N'K5', N'A4', N'C4', 3224)

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PO] OFF
```

DC Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DC]
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [ItemName] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
     [Color] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
     [DCQty] [float] NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_DCQty] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

DC Insert

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DC] ON 
    
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[DC] ([ID], [ItemName], [Color], [DCQty]) 
 VALUES (1, N'A1', N'C1', 9500)

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DC] OFF
```

This is query tried

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        A.PONO, A.ItemName, A.Color, A.POQty,                
        CASE 
            WHEN RN = 1 
                THEN CASE WHEN POQty > B.DCQty 
                              THEN B.DCQty 
                              ELSE POQty 
                     END 
            ELSE 0 
        END DCQty,
        CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN b.DCQty ELSE 0 END DCQty1
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ItemName, Color ORDER BY PONO) RN,
             PONO, ItemName, Color, POQty
         FROM 
             [PO]) A 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [DC] B ON A.ItemName = B.ItemName AND A.Color = B.Color
    WHERE
        A.ItemName = 'A1' AND A.Color = 'C1' 
), 
cte1 AS
(
    SELECT
        PONO, ItemName, Color, POQty, 
        ISNULL(LAG (DCQty1 - DCQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemName, Color ORDER BY PONO), DCQty) DCQty
    FROM
        cte
)    
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         PONO, ItemName, Color, POQty, DCQty, 
         POQty - DCQty POBalQty 
     FROM 
         cte1) a
```

Output is

```
PONO    ItemName    Color    POQty    DCQty    POBalQty
-------------------------------------------------------
K1         A1       C1       5240      5240    0
K2         A1       C1        393      4260    -3867
```

In K2 PONO PO Qty is less than DCQty then it should check the next PO right?

What is wrong here?

Hope everything has been explained in detail for better understanding.

I need to segregate POQty based on DCQty. Here PO and DC Table have a common field name as ItemName and Color based on this column I am matching PO Table with DC Table.

User will pass bulk DCQty. Based on ItemName and Color query should check the PONO and POQty and match that with DCQty.

The condition for each PO NO is DC Qty should be less than PO Qty if DC Qty is greater then PO Qty then query should check for next PO NO and PO Qty

This is expected output

[image]

---

---

**TRIED using temp table**

```
   CREATE TABLE #test(ID INT,DCQty INT);     
   DECLARE @i INT
   SET @i=1
   WHILE @i<=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [PO]) AND 
   (SELECT SUM(POQty) FROM [PO] WHERE ID<=
   CASE WHEN @i=1 THEN 1 ELSE @i-1 END)<=(SELECT DCQty FROM [DC])
   BEGIN 
        
    INSERT INTO #test VALUES(@i,
    CASE WHEN @i=1 THEN (SELECT POQty FROM [PO] WHERE ID=@i)
    WHEN @i>1 AND
    (SELECT POQty FROM [PO] WHERE ID=@i)
   <(SELECT DCQty FROM [DC])-(SELECT SUM(POQty) 
    FROM [PO] WHERE ID<=@i-1)
    THEN (SELECT POQty FROM [PO] WHERE ID=@i)
    WHEN @i>1 AND (SELECT POQty FROM [PO] WHERE ID=@i)
   >(SELECT DCQty FROM [DC])-(SELECT SUM(POQty) FROM [PO] WHERE ID<=@i-1)
   THEN (SELECT DCQty FROM [DC])-(SELECT SUM(POQty) FROM [PO] WHERE ID<=@i-1)
   END)
         
   SET @i=@i+1
  END;
        
  SELECT p.*,t.DCQty,POBa=p.POQty-t.DCQty FROM  [PO] p
  JOIN #test t
  ON p.ID=t.ID
```

**This was temp table above query output**

[image]

**This above query has got 2 issues**

**1st**
If the DC Qty is less than PO Qty then it does not return any resultset I mean the resultset is empty.
Eg: K1 PO Qty is 5240 and DC Qty is 5000 then the result is empty.

**2nd**
If the DC Qty is 5633 which is actually the total qty of PONO K1, K2 which is 5633 of both K1, K2 PO Qty.
Then K2 DC Qty returns as NULL.

**This is expected output**

[image]

Comment: Expected output would help

Comment: Any update on the above query ...

Answer (score 0):

A simple running sum looks like it should work for you

```sql
SELECT
    t.PONO,
    t.ItemName,
    t.Color,
    t.POQty,
    t.DCQty,
    POBalQty = CASE WHEN t.RunningSum - t.DCQty > 0 THEN t.RunningSum - t.DCQty ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT
        PO.PONO,
        PO.ItemName,
        PO.Color,
        PO.POQty,
        DC.DCQty,
        RunningSum = SUM(PO.POQty) OVER (PARTITION BY PO.ItemName, PO.Color
            ORDER BY PO.ID DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM DC
    JOIN PO ON DC.ItemName = PO.ItemName
         AND DC.Color = PO.Color
) t
WHERE t.RunningSum - t.DCQty - t.POQty < 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7a13857a12446e0685256a048695a5d)

Comment: In the above query ... For all the PO NO, DC Qty is taken as 9500.